# Is there an #ifdef to distinguish between Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 beta in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, conditional-compilation

I have a single codebase that needs to be compatible with Xcode 7 beta and Xcode 6.4. This is because beta testing and App Store builds should be built with the stable version of the compiler and SDK, but I also have iOS 9 beta on a phone I use for testing.

This hasn't been a problem with Objective-C, but now that I'm adding a bit of Swift, I'm finding it hard to maintain compatibility with both version of Xcode.

What can I do?

I know Swift has an #ifdef directive, but are there #ifdefs than can distinguish between Swift 1.2 and 2.0? I can't find a list of valid ones for Swift except for DEBUG, os, and arch.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_9_0
    some Swift code that works in Swift 2.0 but won't compile in Swift 1.2
#else
    some Swift code that works in Swift 1.2 but won't compile in Swift 2.0
#endif
```

Or a more concrete example:

```
public final class MessageParser : NSObject {

    #ifdef __IPHONE_9_0
    static let sharedHashtagRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"(^|\\W)(#|\\uFF03)(\\w*\\p{L}\\w*)", options:[]);
    #else
    static let sharedHashtagRegex = NSRegularExpression(pattern:"(^|\\W)(#|\\uFF03)(\\w*\\p{L}\\w*)", options:nil, error:nil)!
    #endif

    // ...
}
```

Comment: "I have a single codebase that needs to be compatible with Xcode 7 beta and Xcode 6.4" It won't be. Forget it. These are two completely different versions of Swift (and of the Cocoa API); you can't possibly write Swift code that works for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, as Swift imposes all "define" path must compile.
sorry but old good times of #ifdef are gone

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not so uncommon. We see it every time when we are in the middle of a heavy code refactoring. What can you do? Use a versioning system, e.g. git.

With git:

Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4) - keep the old code at your `master` branch

Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7.0) - put the migrated code to a new branch, e.g. `features/swift20`.

Now, for a while you will have to mantain two branches but that shouldn't be hard. You can add your changes to `master` and then merge them to `features/swift20`, solving all the collisions/migrations during the merge.

When Xcode 9 GM comes out, you can just merge `features/swift20` into `master` because you won't need Swift 1.2 any more.